# Convert match expressions so I can combine them using combinators like orElse

Tags: scala

I currently have something that looks like:

```
Class UserLocation { 
    def handleUser1(user: User): Unit = user.location match {
        case ... => ..
        case ... => ..
        case _ => ..
    }
}

Class UserLocation2 { 
    def handleUser2(user: User): Unit = user.location match {
        case ... => ..
        case ... => ..
        case _ => ..
    }
}

Class UserLocation3 { 
    def handleUser3(user: User): Unit = user.location match {
        case ... => ..
        case ... => ..
        case _ => ..
    }
}
```

How can I convert the above to a partial function so I can do something like:

```
def handleUser(user: User): Unit = handleUser1(user) orElse handleUser2(user) orElse handleUser3(user)
```

Comment: Did you try writing it as a partial function?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov that is what I need help with

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with the your layout and your goal.  For one thing, all the `handleUser` methods are hidden in their own `class` so the goal, as stated, is impossible because they aren't all in scope at the same time.  They might be pulled into scope by making the classes `implicit`, but for that each class needs a constructor parameter.

So here's one possible solution achieved by dropping all the individual classes.

```
case class User(location: String)

val handleUser1: PartialFunction[User,Unit] = {
  case User("Bern") => println("there")
  case User("NYC")  => println("here")
}

val handleUser2: PartialFunction[User,Unit] = {
  case User("Spain") => println("there")
  case User("USA")   => println("here")
}

val handleUser3: PartialFunction[User,Unit] = {
  case User("moon")  => println("far")
  case User("earth") => println("near")
  case User(_)       => println("unknown")  // the only default
}

val handleUser = handleUser1 orElse handleUser2 orElse handleUser3

handleUser(User("Bern"))  // "there"
handleUser(User("moon"))  // "far"
handleUser(User("Boon"))  // "unknown"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the functions as `PartialFunction`s and then compose them using `orElse`:

```
val f :PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case 1 => 1
}

val f2 :PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case 2 => 2
}

val f3 :PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {
  case 3 => 3
}

def g = f orElse f2 orElse f3

g(1)    // 1
g(2)    // 2
g(3)    // 3
g(4)    // scala.MatchError
```

P.S
@Suma  - Thanks for the input.

Comment: One can use orElse on partial functions directly, not need to lift them for that.

Comment: Nice! Didn't know that, updating my answer. Thanks @Suma